# Spark read delimited csv ignoring escape

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I need to read a csv delimited by "|": each column value is a string and it is included between "".
I use this code to read the file

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter","|").option("escape", "_").option("inferSchema","false").csv("maprfs:///iper/file.txt")
```

Is there a way to ignore and not use the escape character? 
Otherwise how I can delete a special character in the csv file (for example "\" or "_") and reload it as a dataframe?

Comment: can you give an example how your data is and what your desired output?

Comment: can you please provide your sample csv data.